# Adding and View MySql data on one map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For the last couple of days I've been working on a map that can add data through a InfoWindow to a MySQL DB.  I successfully did so by using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3) (`phpsqlinfo_v3`).

Now I need to be able to load all the added markers that are created to the same map.  I followed the instuctions at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) (`phpsqlajax_v3).

I successfully got that to work as well.  The problem I am having is that I can't put the two together.  The only way I can get them to work is by having separate maps.  At the bottom of the first link it states that if you go `phpsqlajax_v3` and skip down to the *create the map* section, you can put it all together.  I've tried what seems to be everything under the sun but and having no luck at all.  Can someone point me in the right direction or lay out what I need to do to get it all to work and on the same map.

Comment: How about some code or a link??

Comment: There are links to the code I used in the question.  Just before the file names.  Thanks.

Comment: A link to what you have done so far

Comment: how do I add the code that I am working on here?  I don't have a test DB up right now but I'd like you to look at the code.  I feel the issue is either with the way I have the marker and infowindow var setup or with the downloadURL settings.  I am very new to the Google API and developing for that matter so it might be very obvious to someone with any knowledge.

Comment: Here is a link to the HTML file: [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F2D277FD6FBE9D53!1230)

Comment: I solved this, I'll post a code example when I get a little time.